# Fetching many objects, but only prefetching for first 20 in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I want to know if I can do want I want in one sql query, currently my database is running slowly in the server and I'm trying to reduce the query's as much as possible.

I need 3 things from the query:

- fetch first 20 objects matching my filter
- prefetch related objects (m2m) **only for the first 20**
- **count all the objects matching my filter**

So far I've only found a way to do this in 2 queries because I can't seem to limit the prefetch without limiting the whole query.

here is my code:

```
images = Image.objects.filter().order_by('-id').distinct().prefetch_related('tags')[:20]
amount = images.count()
```

this results in 2 database queries, how can I make this one?

Comment: It could just be a type, but try ``[:20]`` instead of ``[20]``.

Comment: yeah it's meant to be :20 it was originally a bunch of parameters for pagination that results in the first 20 so i simplified but that irrelevant to my question

Comment: Can you give more information about your Image model - table structure, indexes and what query are you actually doing. I Guess that the root of your performance issues is the way you query the image table.

Answer (score 0):

The above statements are not 2 database queries.
Prefetch_related will make as many db queries as there are m2m relationships for each of the image.
So basically 1 + total_number_of_tags_of_queryset_images

If you don't fetch tags doesn't matter if you fetch 20 or 100 images. It will be 1 query.

So what you are doing is best but get the count first. Otherwise count will be 20 always.

```
count = Images.objects.all().count()
images = Image.objects.all().order_by('-id').distinct().prefetch_related('tags')[:20]
```

So you can't make it in 1 query.